# UITableView cellForRowAt method is not getting executed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

```
extension ArticlesViewController {
    func setup() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    
    newtworkManager?.getNews { [weak self] (results) in
        switch results {
        case .success(let data):
            self?.articleListVM = ArticleListViewModel(articles: data.article!)
            // For testing
            print(self?.articleListVM.articles as Any)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, while debugging, I am receiving data successfully and printing it out. However, I realized the cellForRowAt function is not being executed which is causing the data not showing on the table. I cannot see any issue, but the run time disagrees of course.

```
extension ArticlesViewController {
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.articleListVM == nil ? 0 : self.articleListVM.numberOfSections
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.articleListVM.numberOfRowsInSection(section)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArticleTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("ArticleTableViewCell not found")
    }
    
    let articleVM = self.articleListVM.articleAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    cell.titleLabel.text = articleVM.title
    cell.abstractLabel.text = articleVM.abstract
    return cell
}
```

}

Why do you think this method is not getting triggered? Note that my UITableView and UITableViewCell on the storyboard are connected respectively to my code. I see no reason why it is not loading the data.

Comment: Have you set delegates in viewDidLoad()?
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: @NomanUmar Yup, already did so but to working at all.

Comment: if numberOfRowsInSection > 0 & numberOfSections >= 1, I would then doublecheck your constraints. As a try, you may add `tableView.rowHeight = 50` in your setup and see if it gets called

Comment: @AhmedAlFailakawi If the problem was in returning of 0 raws in numberOfRowsInSection or 0 sections in numberOfSections, and you have found your mistake and problem is solved - please close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main issue was with the global variable `newtworkManager` And as you can see in code:

```
newtworkManager?.getNews {...}
```

The solution was that I deleted this global variable and replaced it with the following:

```
NetworkManager().getNews { ...}
```

After that, cellForRowAt method was working fine and data cells were displayed on the UITableView.

Answer (score 2):

Confirm ArticlesViewController to UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource protocol & remove override for functions.
Example:

```
extension ArticlesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.articleListVM == nil ? 0 : self.articleListVM.numberOfSections
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        ....
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ....
    }
}
```

Also make sure you have connected your tableview via storyboard/code.

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: ```ArticlesViewController``` is an UITableViewController, which already conforms to both protocols UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. While doing more debugging, I noted that cellForRowAt is the one that is not being executed at all.

Comment: Is numberOfRowsInSection function getting executed ..? If yes, what's the number getting returned..?

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection = 0

Comment: Oopss... That's the reason, why cells are not loading.... Add some hardcoded value like return 5 & test, so that cells can load. And, debug this statement "return self.articleListVM == nil ? 0 : self.articleListVM.numberOfSections". This should solve your problem. :)

Comment: You see, I created a similar project it was exactly the same and the code is identical. Main difference is that this one is using a different networking library. While debugging that other project, numberOfSections = 0 with no issue and it is displaying all the data cells perfectly. Why would this be the problem?

Comment: You are getting confused between numberOfSections=0 & numberOfRowsInSection=0. It doesn't matter if numberOfSections = 0, but in order to have the cells in tableview numberOfRowsInSection has to be greater than 0. You can try hardcoding the value for numberOfRowsInSection & add breakpoint in cellForRowAt indexPath to test... :)

Comment: Oh God, I feel so ashamed. numberOfRowsInSection = 20 not zero. My mistake. So, I guess now the problem is not related to numberOfRowsInSection.

Answer (score 0):

How have you layed out the views, programmatically or via Storyboard?

**If done via Storyboard:**

1. Make sure to connect the IBOutlet properly(check for typos etc),
   assign delegate & datasource to the tableviews and conform to the
   protocols.

**If done programmatically:**

1. Make sure you set the delegate and datasource of the data before
   calling `tableView.reloadData()`

   ```
   tableView.dataSource = self
   tableView.delegate = self
   ```

Comment: I have created it through the storyboard and it's seems fine. Datasource and delegate are correctly connected to the IBOutlets.